# Load an Internal file into a div via link without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to when a link is clicked on the side of the page grab a another page from my site thats in the same directory and show it into a div called content.

::Optionally:: if i could figure out an easy way to do it without a refresh otherwise refresh the page.

link is

```
<a href="#" id="servicecall">Service Call</a>
```

my jquery was...not sure if it would work

```
$("#servicecall").click(function() {
  $("#content").load("servicecall.php");
});
```

Content is my div on the right side where the servicecall.php form would be.
All that seems to happen is my page does a refresh and nothing shows up in content.

Comment: do not abuse tags. Your question is not PHP nor CSS related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button it gives back an error or something? For example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9839Q/4/
When i click the Service Call link it gives me an error with the following line (Chrome):

GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/index.php 404 (NOT FOUND)

Be sure you added the jQuery Library to your page ! Maybe you just forgot it

```
<script src="http: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery. min .js"></script> //without spaces
```

If none of them, you can try $.ajax (hope it works :)) :

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "servicecall.php",  
    type: "GET",            
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {  
        //place servicecall.php's content to the content div
        $('#content').html(html);   
    }       
});
```

Comment: No error i also tried to put an alert into the click function and the alert works fine when i click it so i think it has to do with the load function.

Comment: my jquery library is in my page because jquery is working with other parts ill try ajax and hopefully it works thx

Comment: for me your code is working fine too. Are you sure you have a `#content` on your page? (where the code is, not in the servicecall.php.